# why does my simple rust app not exit properly? -> It does but cleansup mem

Tags: rust

TL;DR: Rust cleans up its used memory, so my test app finished a bit later.

I am playing with rust a bit, and have a few versions of
"calculate fib for 10 seconds and gimme the result"
which work fine, but this one does not:

it does not exit, and i cannot find why,
i looked into play.rust-lang.org but adding the num-bigint cargo is not possible i guess
and cloning the reop and adding it into the fiddler is to much of a hassle.

so: this is my fairly simple code

main.rs

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn fibonacci(n: usize, memo: &mut HashMap<usize, BigUint>) -> BigUint {
    match n {
        0 => BigUint::from(0u32),
        1 => BigUint::from(1u32),
        _ => {
            if memo.contains_key(&n) {
                memo.get(&n).unwrap().clone()
            } else {
                let result = fibonacci(n - 1, memo) + fibonacci(n - 2, memo);
                memo.insert(n, result.clone());
                result
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut memo: HashMap<usize, BigUint> = HashMap::new();
    while start_time.elapsed() < Duration::from_secs(10) {
        fibonacci(i, &mut memo);
        i += 1;
    }
    println!("The highest Fibonacci number calculated in 10 seconds was Fibonacci({})", i - 1);
}
```

and cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "grrs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
num-bigint = "0.4"
```

I dont see what i did wrong, but rust usually is pretty safe, so...
Also, other versions like

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};

fn main() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let mut fib_prev: BigUint = BigUint::from(0u32);
    let mut fib: BigUint = BigUint::from(1u32);

    while start_time.elapsed() < Duration::from_secs(10) {
        let temp = fib.clone();
        fib = fib + &fib_prev;
        fib_prev = temp;
        i += 1;
    }
    println!("The highest Fibonacci number calculated in 10 seconds was Fibonacci({})", i - 1);
}
```

do exit just fine, so i am not sure if i have to manage the mem of the hashset or sth?

oh, i installed current rust with rustup on win yesterday if that matters.

thanks

I tried to write a rust app, which actually works, but it does not exit,
i expected the rust app to exit when it is finished computing fib after 10 seconds.

edit: it does finish after cleaning up the used mem i suppose, just took additional 20 second or so. Could have easily checked that in a cmd window with task manager looking at ram usage. thanks

Comment: Does your program not exit at all, or does it exit later (e.g. after 20s instead of 10s)?

Comment: not at all, i run it with rust run and rust run --release with no difference.
but only this "version" others exit as expected (also ones using hashmap) so i am a bit confused.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it does finish, it just takes a lot longer (31.1s for me) than 10s because first it has to finish the last `fibonacci` call that it started just before 10s were up, then it prints, and then it has to do the cleanup as well. Also `num-bigint` is available on the playground.

Comment: This time might be significantly higher when you don't have a lot of memory as at least for me it easily fills ub 20GB+ of memory in those 10s + x you give it to calculate.

Comment: I actually tested the wrong thing. Yes, in the cmd window this also takes about 20 secs after println to clean up, so this seems to be the thing. I could have used the cmd and task manager to observe the mem usage instead of stack overflowing. 
Maybe next time., Thank You for your help.

Comment: The memory usage of your code scales with the square of `i`, i.e. the code uses Ω(i²) of memory. This grows really quickly. If you want to be able to compute high Fibonacci numbers, you should use [binary matrix powering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form). (All you need are the formulae at the end of the linked section.)